# Drag View and Drop it on RecyclerView item Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I am developing an android application that has a screen contains the following:

1. Recycler view that contains categories as the below figure
2. Separate view at the botton and the user should able to drag it on a RecyclerView item, and after drop the user will show changing at the RecyclerView item data (for example items count at the category)

I need some help about how to implement this process 
to drag View into Recycler item, the following figure explains exactly what I want to do but have no idea how to do it

[image]

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start by adding a draglistener to your inflated view in `onCreateViewHolder` of your recycler adapter.

```
view.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {

        switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // drag has started, return true to tell that you're listening to the drag
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // the dragged item was dropped into this view
                Category a = items.get(getAdapterPosition());
                a.setText("dropped");
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                // the drag has ended
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

In the `ACTION_DROP` case you can either change the model and call `notifyItemChanged()`, or modify directly the view (that won't handle the rebinding case). Also in `onCreateViewHolder` add a `longClickListener` to your `View`, and in `onLongClick` start the drag:

```
ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) view.getTag());
String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
ClipData dragData = new ClipData(view.getTag().toString(),
            mimeTypes, item);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new DragShadowBuilder(view);

if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.N) {
    view.startDragAndDrop(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
} else {
    view.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
}
```

For more information about drag and drop check out the [android developers site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: Thanks alot, it looks greate, but I have simple question how to get the adapter view position ?
Thanks

Comment: with `viewholder.getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: Thanks alot!

Exact answer which i needed