# Drag and Drop Recycler View item to Image View

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I want to drag and drop recycler view item image to my image view (which is in main layout ). How Can I achieve this ?

**I am using below code to longItemClickRecyclerViewItem**

```
images_recycler.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), images_recycler ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {


                }
            })
    );




public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener
{
    public static interface OnItemClickListener
    {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
     }

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener)
    {
        mListener = listener;

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
            {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
            {
                View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

                if(childView != null && mListener != null)
                {
                    mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildPosition(childView));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e)
    {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if(childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e))
        {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent){}

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Please help me with some example or code 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my answer here [Drag View and Drop it on RecyclerView item Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066261/drag-view-and-drop-it-on-recyclerview-item-android/42067219#42067219) .
But you'll have to make some changes here. Set a `longClickListener` to your recycler view `iteView` in your `onCreateViewHolder` method where you inflate it. There you start the drag. Set the `onDragListener` though to your `ImageView` where you want to drop it.

**EDIT**

Okay i'm adding some code here. In your `onCreateViewHolder` of your recycler adapter add these lines:

```
@Override
public MemberHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, parent, false);
    view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) view.getTag());
            String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
            ClipData dragData = new ClipData(view.getTag().toString(),
                    mimeTypes, item);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            HeptagonDragShadowBuilder myShadow = new HeptagonDragShadowBuilder(Heptagon.this, 1.1f);

            if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.N) {
                view.startDragAndDrop(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
            } else {
                view.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    return memberHolder;
}
```

On your image view where you want to drop the item add these lines:

```
imageView.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {

        switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // drag has started, return true to tell that you're listening to the drag
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // the dragged item was dropped into this view
                Category a = items.get(getAdapterPosition());
                a.setText("dropped");
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                // the drag has ended
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2**
Okay here's an explanation. When you assign a listener to a view you're telling that you want to listen to drag events. When a drag event starts, the listener's  onDrag gets fired with action `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED`. In this case, on the views listeners where you want to drop the item you return true to tell that this view wants to catch the dragging item. When a view is dropped on the view that you're listening `onDrag` gets fired again with action `DragEvent.ACTION_DROP`. There you'll have to implement the logic what you want to do when the item is dropped. If you want to change the image source of the imageview or replace the imageview you'll have to implement the replacing logic down there in the `DragEvent.ACTION_DROP` case. The drag event and the listener will only tell you that you're dragging and where you're dropping. So any other logic has to be done by you. In my case I notified my recyclerview adapter that certain item has changed.

Comment: can you please explain in detail or provide some code for the changes I need to do ?

Comment: Okay i made some edits to the answer. You can delete your posted code first though you don't really need it.

Comment: If you want more information about how the drag and drop works checkout the [android developers site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: ok Thanks but just tell me what is this class HeptagonDragShadowBuilder ?

Comment: Yep this is just a custom `DragShadowBuilder`. The drag shadow is the view that gets drawn while youre dragging it. I needed a custom view for it. You can use `DragShadowBuilder dragShadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(view);` instead. It will draw the view that you're dragging.

Comment: uhm if the answer helped would you mind upvoting and accepting the answer?

Comment: Hi I can drag the item with this code how about dropping it on my image view ?? what is this line items.get(getAdapterPosition());

Comment: I will surely mark correct and upvote as soon I get out from this prob

Comment: ignore that items.get(getAdapterPosition()). It was just specific for my case. Read the docs to fully understand how to drop [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: can you provide me some example code for dropping with recycler view ?

Comment: Well the code is already there on my answer but i added an explanation

Comment: Thanks with its help I was able to achieve my goal.